# Laravel Fetching one to Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

Hello I am learning laravel and I am having an issue retrieving data from my relations.

In my database there are Product and Groups filled with dummy data.

I defined my relationship like this in product model:

```
     public function Group()
        {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Groups','product_id', 'id');
      }
```

And in my group vice versa with :

```
      public function Product()
      {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id', 'id');
      }
```

The way I am referencing to my products table is :

```
     $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Now I have column product_id in my database under groups, and it is linked to if from products id it seems.

The groups table contains of its auto incremented id and product_id foreign key column.

While products table has auto incremented id and name column.

The issue is here : 
How do I return the products that are not null or have value (of products id) in groups table.

---

I tried something like this in my filter controller:

```
        public function getProductsWithGroup()
{

      $Products = Product::with('groups')->get();
     return $Products ;

}
```

But that is giving me call to undefined relations.

I am not sure how to access belongsTo or hasMany methods and whether I need an extra group_id column in my products table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the relationship wrong. It should be `groups` & define in lowercase as

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Groups','product_id', 'id');
}
```

And use `->has()` to check existence

```
public function getProductsWithGroup()
{
    $Products = Product::has('groups')->get();
    return $Products ;
}
```

`->with()` is used to **eager load** and `->has()` is used to check **existence** & **filter**.

To get the products don't have any groups,

```
$Products = Product::doesntHave('groups')->get();
```

To see other ways to use `->has()` check, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thank you for your time, how about hasNot ? the opposite of this. Oh just found it its doesntHave.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check the link for other complex ways to use `->has()`

Comment: Thank you one more time. I will investigate this.